# jQuery-how can I make my function able to fire more than once?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery but I understand the basic syntax. What I can't find although I've searched and searched is how to make a function able to fire more than once.
Here is a link to my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLu6ysod/) code.

```
    $( "div" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( this ).css("transform", "translate(50px,0px)");
    });
```

In this code I am basically telling a div to move 50px to the right when clicked, but after being clicked once if clicked again nothing happens. How can I make it so that the function will fire again if clicked again?

DISCLAIMER: Sorry if this is a stupid question, like I said before, I'm new to jQuery.

Thank you to all who helped me, I really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Try using +50px .. The way you have it puts it at a static position. Simply replacing with "+50px" does not work, but that is the basis for your math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is telling the div to go 50px left of 0,0.  That will put it in the same spot no matter how much you click it.

You'll have to increment your left position by 50 from current.

Try this:

```
$( "div" ).on( "click", function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    var left = pos.left + 50;

  $( this ).css("transform", "translate("+left+"px,0px)");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is correct, and it does fire more than once. The reason the div doesn't move is because it is already at the position you are trying to move it to.

You are not telling it to move 50px to the right of its current position, but to move 50px to the right of its **original** position. Since it is already there after the first press, it doesn't move.

Example solution:

```
(function(){ //this is only neccessary so that pos doesn't have to be global variable
    var pos = 0;
    $( "div" ).on( "click", function() {
        pos+=50;
        $( this ).css("transform", "translate("+pos+"px,0px)");
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see you take the offset on each click and then add 50.

```
$("div").on("click", function () {
    var offsetL = $(this).position().left;
    $(this).css("transform", "translate(" + (offsetL + 50) + "px,0px)");
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oLu6ysod/8/

Answer (score 0):

test this code

```
var transform = 0 ;
$( "div" ).click(function() {
$( this ).css("transform", "translate("+transform+"px,0px)");
   transform+=50;
});
```

you should renew position each time you clicked on the element